# Why when I go to localhost/my_app/admin I was redirected to localhost/my_app/webroot/admin ? Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cakephp 3.8 and I have developed an admin access, but when I try to access to them by the url : `localhost/admin` my browser (chrome) redirects me systematically to `localhost/my_app/webroot/admin`

This problem doesn't appear when I put a slash at the end : `localhost/my_app/admin/`

Also, I tested on Edge and Firefox and there is no problem, I can access to `localhost/admin` (without the slash at the end)

The route.php :

```
    $routes->connect('/admin', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'admin']);
    Router::prefix('admin', ['param' => 'value'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/:controller');
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action');
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/**');
    });
```

Sorry for my bad english,

Thank you very much for you'r help.

Comment: Try it in an incognito window, if it works, then clearing the browser cache will probably fix it.

Comment: @ndm Hi,yes it's work in incognito tab ! So I have cleared my browser's cache and I have no longer the problem ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 years, I found the real solution :
My problem is that I've a folder named "admin" in my webroot, just give another name to the folder and clear navigator cache and it solve the problem.

Comment: Props for coming back to and answering your old question :). For future reference, the headers in the redirect help diagnose what is responsible for such behavior (I'm assuming it was the webserver) although this answer does not explain, and conflicts with, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021230/why-when-i-go-to-localhost-my-app-admin-i-was-redirected-to-localhost-my-app-web#comment107968472_61021230).

Answer (score -1):

I think that your application have outdated cache. Try to clear all your sessions and cache and refresh your page. I think that it will solve your problem.